# Xcode -> Build starting with a specific class

Tags: xcode, applet, compilation

When I build with Xcode (I am porting a large project with tons of errors at this point), is there a way to have it start with the CPP file that contains my main class (I obviously know this file) so I can correct errors there first?

I mean we have about 400,000 errors moving from CW to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compile that file on its own: select the file and then `Build` => `Compile` (or just Command-K). Once you have all the errors fixed there you can move on to a full build.